# mongorestore uncaught exception: syntax error

Tags: mongodb

I've dumped some databases using `mongodump` which means that I currently have a folder(which name, is the date I dumped the databases) and one folder for each database that I had and inside each database folder I have 2 files per collection, one .bson and one .metadata.json.

Now I want to use `mongorestore` to rebuild databases and their collections using the following command:

```
 mongorestore --db user --verbose /home/nvsh120/projects/database/11-26-20/user
```

but it doesn't work and exits with the following error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:15
```

Comment: mongorestore is unlikely to be capable of producing that error since it's not written in javascript, nor does it include a mongo shell.

Comment: @D.SM Thank you for you'r reply, I found the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the problem was that I was trying to run `mongorestore` from mongo shell whereas I should've run it from windows\linux command prompt\terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this, it is for running a `mongorestore` command for a docker pulled DB.

You cannot run the `mongorestore` in the docker mongo shell.

First run the command to get the bash of the specific docker container:

```
sudo docker exec -it <name-of-container> bash
```

Next, run the restore command in this bash.

```
root@52f66390ae10:/# mongorestore -d <db-name> <path-to-dump-in-docker-container>
```

Keep in mind, I have run my Docker MongoDB with a docker-compose.yml file in which I have mounted the database dump as a volume.

Here is a snippet from the docker-compose file:

```
volumes:
            - <path-to-dump-in-local>:<path-to-db-in-container> (Usually /data/db)
```

Volumes can also be mounted as a part of the docker run command.